# How to Check if Multi-Dimensional Associative Array is Empty

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array as follows:

```
$list_array = array();

$list_array[] = array (
                 'id' => 1,
                 'name' => 'Sean',
                 'codename' => 'Maverick'
                 );

$list_array[] = array (
                 'id' => 2,
                 'name' => 'Matt',
                 'codename' => 'Diesel'
                 );

$list_array[] = array (
                 'id' => 3,
                 'name' => 'Bonnie',
                 'codename' => 'Princess'
                 );
```

I am trying to figure out how I can check to see if it's empty.  I look on the site and tried a couple of things, but it's not working.  Here are the things I've tried.

```
Attempt 1:
if (empty($list_array)
    echo "Array is empty";


Attempt 2:
$arr_empty = true;
$arr_length = count($list_array);
echo "Length: " . $arr_length . "<br>";
for ($z=1; $z<=$arr_length; $z++)
{
    $arr_length2 = count($list_array[$z]);
    echo $z . " Length2: " . $arr_length2 . "<br>";
    if (empty($list_array[$z]))
        echo $z . " Is Empty<br>";
}
```

I feel like I'm missing the obivious here.

Comment: your declaration of array is missing an `array` keyword. sample: `$list_array[] = array('values');`

Comment: That was an oversight in my post, not in my actual code.  I have corrected it.

Comment: `count($list_array)` will be 0 for an empty array. If it's anything but 0 and you think the array is empty, then it's not. Maybe the array is getting repopulated in some other part of code

Comment: count gives me 5, count(list_array[x]) gives me 4, vardump gives me: array(5) { [1]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> NULL ["name"]=> NULL ["codename"]=> NULL ["kills"]=> NULL } [2]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> NULL ["name"]=> NULL ["codename"]=> NULL ["kills"]=> NULL } [3]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> NULL ["name"]=> NULL ["codename"]=> NULL ["kills"]=> NULL } [4]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> NULL ["name"]=> NULL ["codename"]=> NULL ["kills"]=> NULL } [5]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> NULL ["name"]=> NULL ["codename"]=> NULL ["kills"]=> NULL } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

empty should work:

```
if (empty($list_array))
    echo "Array is empty";
else
    echo "Array is not empty";
```

Your loop does not work because PHP arrays are zero based, you should start with zero and continue while `$z < $arr_length`

Comment: It was that damn 0, like I said, something obvious

Answer (score 2):

There are a few PHP functions for this that all do slightly different things:

---

`isset` — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

**Example:**

`if(isset($list_array)){//do something}` will do something if $list_array is set to a value other than NULL.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

---

`empty` — Determine whether a variable is empty. This function returns `true` if the variable or array is an empty string, false, array(), NULL, 0 or an unset variable. I prefer the use of the `empty` function.

**Example:**

```
if(!empty($list_array)){
    //do something with array here, such as a foreach or while loop.
}
```

See: https://www.php.net/empty

---

`is_null` — Identifies whether or not a variable is NULL by returning either true or false. It returns true only when the variable is null. `is_null()` is opposite of `isset()`, except for one difference that `isset()` can also be applied to unknown variables whereas `is_null()` can only be used for declared variables.

**Example:**
`if(is_null($var)){ //do something }`

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

---

Let's stick with `empty`:

```
if(empty($list_array)){ $msg = "Array is empty!"; }
if(!isset($msg)){echo $msg;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found two errors in your code:

1. a parenthesis is not closed in Attempt 1
2. in your for cycle you are starting from 1 instead of starting from 0 (so, you are considering that the array will be something like `array(1=>..., 2=>..., 3=>...)`, while it is actually `array(0=>..., 1=>..., 2=>...)`

So, here is your code, fixed:

```
$list_array = array();

$list_array[] = array (
                 'id' => 1,
                 'name' => 'Sean',
                 'codename' => 'Maverick'
                 );

$list_array[] = array (
                 'id' => 2,
                 'name' => 'Matt',
                 'codename' => 'Diesel'
                 );

$list_array[] = array (
                 'id' => 3,
                 'name' => 'Bonnie',
                 'codename' => 'Princess'
                 );

//Attempt 1:
if (empty($list_array))
    echo "Array is empty";


//Attempt 2:
$arr_empty = true;
$arr_length = count($list_array);
echo "Length: " . $arr_length . "<br>";
for ($z=0; $z<$arr_length; $z++)
{
    $arr_length2 = count($list_array[$z]);
    echo $z . " Length2: " . $arr_length2 . "<br>";
    if (empty($list_array[$z]))
        echo $z . " Is Empty<br>";
}
```

You can try it [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/), with a simple copy and paste.